# How do I find where day are 5 and null at the same time in sqflite on flutter?

Tags: sql, sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

How do I find where day are 5 and null in the column at the same time in sqflite on flutter?

```
final templates = await db.query(
  Constants.dbTable,
  where: "${Constants.dbColDays} LIKE ?",
  whereArgs: ['%${day}%', 'IS NULL'],
);
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it

```
final templates = await db.query(
  Constants.dbTable,
  where: "${Constants.dbColDays} LIKE ? OR ${Constants.dbColDays} IS NULL",
  whereArgs: ['%${day}%'],
);
```